# SainSmart Support for TFT 7 inch display

Tags: raspbian

I'm trying to hook SainSmart's 7 inch display to my raspberry pi.  It hooks up and sort of works, but it shows red lines in the command mode and has a super red background when in GUI mode.  Maybe I have the wrong drivers?  I tried calling SainSmart but the number on their website was disconnected.  Any ideas?